# Is it justified to criticize about an existing answer and at the same time attack the other answerer calling them out by name?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, specific-answer, abuse, specific-comment

This question is in reference to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57165298/how-to-find-the-second-occurence-of-find-element-by-class-name/57168459#57168459) where the answerer have not only criticized an existing answer but also at the same time attacked the other answerer through name calling.

Snapshot:

> [image: personal_attack]

My questions are:

- Is *criticizing an existing answer* justified?
- Is attacking the other answerers calling them out by name?
- Isn't this behavior *abusive*?
- If yes, how should we deal with these kind of situation?

Comment: How is that attacking anyone? Or abusive in any way? Why couldn’t you criticize other posts (while doing it respectfully)?

Comment: "Name calling" in English doesn't mean literally using the person's name, it means [calling the person some sort of insult](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/name-calling). You probably meant to use the term "Calling out a user by name."

Comment: This is why it's almost impossible to be "welcoming". Anything and everything will be interpreted as a personal attack - no matter the intention.

Comment: Wait. Your name *isn't* DebanjanB?  Or were you more referring to the part where they called you by name?  Name calling and calling someone by name are different and carry different connotations.

Comment: Very slightly related: *[Begging for Votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63439/begging-for-votes)*

Comment: Criticizing answers helps you, and everyone else, to learn. Not all ideas are good, and answers or comments pointing that out (assuming it's not done in a rude way obviously) are usually constructive not just for the answerer, but for OP and other readers. That is far from attacking by the way. If the answer was one massive rant explaining why the answer is terrible and why you should feel terrible for suggesting it, then yes, that would be attacking. That isn't what's going on here.

Comment: One problem with referring to another answer by username is that the other answerer may change their name at some point, which may make it confusing as to which post was being referenced. In that sense, a link to the other answer would probably be better.

Comment: @Don'tPanic that's why it's helpful to include a link to the user's profile

Comment: @YvetteColomb Wouldn't it be even better to link to the other answer instead of the user who wrote that other answer?

Comment: @AndréKool true!

Answer (score 42):

> Is criticizing an existing answer justified?

Yes. Pointing out flaws in existing answers is considered acceptable behaviour.

> Is attacking the other answerers through name calling justified?

There is no attack here. He simply pointed out the name, so that future readers would know what answer he was referring to.

> Isn't this behavior abusive?

No. He is pointing out a flaw in your answer, which is not considered abusive. Now, it is possible that he is incorrect, and that this flaw does not exist (I haven't bothered to check), but being wrong would also not be abusive.

Comment: Latest bullet: "If yes, how should we deal with these kind of situation?" Assuming it was abusive behavior you had the option to flag the post as rude/abusive.

Answer (score 33):

As the writer of the answer being discussed, I wanted to come here and explain what I did and why... not only to DebajanB but to other readers. Feel free to give me feedback in the comments if you feel that I did something "wrong" or could improve my answer in approach (or even answer content).

I originally downvoted DebanjanB's answer because it gave misleading information and explained why I downvoted in my comment. After a few hours had passed... the answer wasn't corrected, OP asked me for more details on my comment, DebanjanB updated his answer but OP responded that it still didn't work. (I'm not sure why the OP accepted his answer if it didn't work but I chalked it up to OP being new to the site.)

At this point, there were no other answers and in order to answer OP's question to me, I couldn't have explained in any detail in the comments so I wrote my own answer. I started my answer by giving the most straightforward answer, which was basically a small adaptation of OP's attempt. I then explained how I approach problems like this and during that explanation, I expanded on my comment as to why XPath is not a good solution in general (with references) and why it's especially error-prone in this particular situation. I referenced DebanjanB's specific XPath and explained why it was the less optimal solution. My intention was not to attack him personally but just to reference his answer (and I think I succeeded or did I?).

Comment: Yeah you did. He's just having a bad day, feeling attacked from 0 attack answer.

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong.

Comment: To be 100% safe you're talking about the content of the answer and not about the person instead of *If you used the XPath that DebanjanB suggested,* you could have said *If you used the XPath that [this answer](link to answer) suggested,* but I doubt if that would have prevented this Meta. If you feel like being attacked, any phrase used will confirm that pre-position.

Comment: @rene exactly..